# Finding unmanaged files that are older than 6 months

Tags: find

I'm trying to find all files that haven't been touched for 6 months or longer. I ran this command but it just shows all files that were edited 6 months a go.

```
find . -type f -mtime 183 -exec ls -latr {} \;
```

How would I make this so it's 6 months or more?

Comment: `-mtime +183` would be for files whose age rounded up to the next 24 hour unit is strictly greater than 183. So that includes files modified 183*24*3600+0.00000001 seconds ago and older.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mtime 183` is for files whose age rounded up to the next 24-hour period is equal to 183, so for ages comprised between 182*24*3600 seconds (exclusive) and 183*24*3600 seconds (inclusive) (where seconds are Unix seconds, that is have a variable duration that is the 86400<sup>th</sup> part of the earth day, not the fixed duration ISO definition of the second. So all days are 86400 seconds, we don't need to account for leap seconds).

With `-mtime +183`, you get files whose age rounded up to the next 24 hour period is strictly greater than 183, so that for ages strictly greater than 183*24*3600 seconds.

Note that 24 hour period is not necessarily the same as *day* because of daylight saving time switches in some regions.

With some `find` implementations (FreeBSD, GNU), you can also use `! -newermt '6 months ago'`. `mt` compares the `m`odification time with the `t`ime given as argument.

That will give files modified before the same day of the month, same hour 6 months ago, but in the case of GNU `find` (as opposed to FreeBSD) it doesn't do the DST adjustment (in timezones where DST applies), that is it gives you the information as if in a UTC timezone. If now is 2016-07-01 13:00 (summer time), FreeBSD `find` would report files last modified before 2016-01-01 13:00 (winter time), while GNU `find` would report files last modified before 2016-01-01 12:00 (winter time). There might be variations as well when called on the 29th, 30th or 31st of the month and the month 6 months ago has no such date.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `+` in front of the day value. From the man page:

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,

   -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.
```

and

```
... When  find  figures  out
how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, any
fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

Although this refers to the `atime` test, it is the same for the `mtime` and `ctime` tests.