# mtime - Set date format

Tags: find, filenames, date

Looking over the manual, I can't figure out how to set the date format.

I am using the following to locate folders that are in 'dd-mm-yyyy' name, but realise that it may not be working due to the date format.

Is there any way to set the date format of '-mtime'?

```
find "${backup_dest}" \
    -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +3 \
    -name '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' \
    -execdir mv {} $folder_trash_path/{}-"${site[$i]}" ';'
```

Comment: Your `find` command is searching for _directories_, but your question description refers to _files_. Which is it?

Comment: @roaima Sorry, its folders. I have changed this in the question.

Comment: is `-maxdepth 1` throwing you off? (are the directories in question in the $backup_dest directory, or below it?)

Comment: @JeffSchaller The folders are directly inside the $backup_dest folder. Here is an example: /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testsite.co.uk/19-06-2018 - The $backup_dest would be: /Users/myname/Desktop/backups/websites/testsite.co.uk

Comment: Just want to point out that the example you just gave is today’s date, and would not pass “-mtime +3”

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry, bad example. I have folders of 16-06-2018.

Comment: Ok; is it that mtime +3 requires the matches to be > 3 days (e.g. 4 days)? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314206/finding-unmanaged-files-that-are-older-than-6-months/314211?s=2|16.5575#314211 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441314/how-to-delete-all-the-files-which-are-not-created-today/441317#441317

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79089/discussion-between-ccdavies-and-jeff-schaller).

Answer (score 0):

Old find(1) implementatons and the POSIX standard only allow `-mtime` parameters that are plain numbers and that refer to a time offset that counts in days.

Modern find(1) implementations permit something like: `-mtime -3y2m4d` referring to all files that have been modified during the past 3 years + 2 months + 4 days.

If you like to refer to a specific time, then you may only use `-newer` together with a time stamp reference file that could be created with the `touch` program.

Comment: It seems to be BSD find that implements units, GNU find doesn't have that yet (BUT IT SHOULD!)

Comment: @deltaray These units are an obvious idea that I already had around 1988 and `sfind`, which is based on `libfind` also supports it. BTW: GNU find was the last find implementation that started to implement -exec ... {} +, so GNU find may not be the leading edge regarding to useful features.